# How to get the element's top offset to <body> when they are inside a <HTML> with 2 column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

**The Question**

As you can see in the picture. We have a very long BODY element.
When we put it to a HTML with column set as 2, the BODY will automatically break into two parts. As shown in the picture on the right side.

Now we want to get the top offset of SPAN to BODY (value of V1 in the picture). We have tried a lot of method but none of them returns the right value.

**What We Have Done**

We have tried jQuery's position() and offset(). They all returns the value V3 (FYI, V1=V2+V3), not what we need. We Can not get V1 by V2+V3 due to the design of our App, it may has more column than this demonstration.

**Thank you very much.**

Comment: My first suggestion would be not to have `<body>` split into columns, work with elements inside it instead.

Comment: can provide a fiddle or working link